# jenkins fails to start correctly, despite lack of error output

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, devops

So, I've seen answers for when Jenkins totally fails to start. It looks like I have a slightly different problem where Jenkins runs but then immediately exits.

After an EC2 instance reboot, I tried this:

```
λ ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx jenkinshome → sudo service jenkins start
Starting jenkins (via systemctl):                          [  OK  ]

λ ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx jenkinshome → sudo service jenkins status
● jenkins.service - LSB: Jenkins Automation Server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (exited) since Fri 2020-11-13 22:32:56 UTC; 3s ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 14875 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 14897 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 Nov 13 22:32:55 xx...xx systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Jenkins Automation Server...
 Nov 13 22:32:55 xx...xx runuser[14902]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
 Nov 13 22:32:56 xx...xx systemd[1]: Started LSB: Jenkins Automation Server.
 Nov 13 22:32:56 xx...xx jenkins[14897]: Starting Jenkins [  OK  ]
```

Additionally, running `java -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war` just seems to install and start a new jenkins instance, rather than starting my previously running jenkins instance.

Worth noting: I'm at very little free space left on my device, and there are significant admin hurdles for cleaning disk space and for getting more space allocated, though this may be related.

Not quite sure how to proceed, but any tips are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: did you check `systemctl status jenkins` for details of what is going on

Comment: @Saravanan - yes, the output is equivalent to the output of `sudo service jenkins status` above in my distro (RHEL)

Comment: The following doesn't do exactly what I'd wanted, but it effectively restores my jenkins configuration given that I have an existing jenkins_home folder at `/var/lib/jenkins`:

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v /var/lib/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts` where the jenkins tag should be fixed not to lts but to the version of jenkins that corresponds to one's pre-existing installation.

Effectively, this installs and runs jenkins from within `docker`, but restores the configuration from my `/var/lib/jenkins` folder. One also has to reconfigure any ssh keys, etc.

Comment: I don't understand, are you using Docker or not? `we do not have jenkins running within a docker container`

Comment: @PierreB. we had not, prior to my debugging, but I was able to restore some of what we had before by mounting a jenkins docker container on the existing /var/lib/jenkins directory on  our machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was fairly straightforward, and dare I say obvious: I needed to reinstall jenkins. I'm on RHEL, but this could be adapted for ubuntu, etc. (see link below).

```sh
# stop the jenkins service altogether
sudo service jenkins stop

# backup jenkins_home files
sudo cp -r /var/lib/jenkins ~/.jenkins_home_backup 

# remove the jenkins installation entirely
sudo yum remove jenkins # remove existing jenkins install

# add the jenkins ssh key locally
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key

# reinstall jenkins
sudo yum -y install jenkins

# start jenkins!
sudo service jenkins start
```

More or less adapted from: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-jenkins-on-centos-rhel-8/

You may need to also reference: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/07/27/repository-signing-keys-changing/

Answer (score 1):

1. Unlock an HTTP port and provide the Firewall access by executing below two commands

   ```sh
   firewall-cmd --permanent -add-port=<port_num>/tcp
   firewall-cmd --reload
   ```
2. Start Jenkins by providing the user-defined port number:

   ```sh
   java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=<port_num>
   ```

If the issue still exists, then check the space of that directory where Jenkins running. If not enough space, then move that Jenkins to another directory where enough space exists.

#### Check Directory level permission and also file level permissions.

Hope it will work for your issue!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: This didn't quite work for me - it just restarted the other instance of jenkins. Appreciate the help though! Have an upvote and the bounty - I learned something regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me -

```
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/cache/jenkins
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/log/jenkins
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```